# How can I document and autocomplete a class parameters including its parent parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop

I am having dificulties trying to create a more readable class that inherits from a parent. This is a simple example of what my problem is:

I have a class, lets call it Car:

```py
class Car():
    def __init__(self, model, color, type, *args, **kargs):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.type = type
```

and a child class that inherits from car:

```py
class SportsCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, type, horse_power, *args, **kargs):
        """__summary___
            Args:
                model <str> model of the car
                ...
        """
        super().__init__(model=model, color=color, type=type, *args, **kargs)
```

In order to achieve the best doccumentation and autocompletion of arguments I could. However, I wonder if there is any better method to do this? Is there no way to pass these arguments easily? Especially when there are a lot of arguments to be passed to the parent, is there no way to simply tell python I want to include the parent's arguments in my child's component? I did not use *args, **kargs since I have required arguments that I want to show in the IDE and autocomplete them...

Comment: I don't think there's any better ways to be honest. You could ask for the required args in your child class and make the parent class just accept a dictionary, and make it parse those args on its own. Whenever I have tried something like that the trend I realize is, the more you try to make something generic the less readable/clear and concise it becomes and vice versa, so I guess its a trade off at the end of the day

Comment: maybe (partially) helpful [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)